# Get the line cart items count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, cart

I'm trying to find a way of getting the unique cart count from a woocommerce basket. After looking at the documentation it only shows a way to get the total count

```
get_cart_contents_count( )
```

Does anyone know of a way to get the unique count. For example if I add 50 pieces of product A and 20 pieces of product B, I just want the cart count to be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make the trick *(counting cart line items)*:

```
echo '<p>Line cart items count: ' . count( WC()->cart_get_cart() ) . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

---

For line order items count it will be *(from the `WC_Order` `$order` object)*:

```
echo '<p>Line order items count: ' . count( $order->get_items() ) . '</p>';
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I editted slightly to work within my themes namespace

function unique_cart_count( $atts ){
  global $woocommerce;
  $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
  return count($cart);
 }
 add_shortcode( 'unique_cart_count', __NAMESPACE__.'\\unique_cart_count' );